# Use Select and Select many Together in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the company id in the following query.

```
List<int> companyIds=new List<int> {4, 5, 6, 7};
   var result = reservationRepository.Where(r => companyIds.Contains(r.CompanyId))
                .SelectMany(t =>  t.Transactions)
                .Where(x => x.DateCreated >= options.PaymentFromDate)
                .Where(x => x.DateCreated < endDate)
                .Select(x => new 
                {
                    Method = x.Method,
                    Amount = x.Amount,
                    VatAmount = x.VatAmount
                });
```

Since I am using `select many` I am not able to get `companyId`. Please suggest a way to return company id also along with the result.

The reservation table contains CompanyId. Transaction doesnot contain Company Id

```
public class Reservation{
  public int CompanyId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction{
  public string Method{ get; set; }
  public decimal Amount{ get; set; }
  public decimal VatAmount{ get; set; }
 
}
```

I have to start the query with the Reservation table because I am getting the corresponding transactions from it. **I can't change the model.  Is there any way we can get both transaction details and CompanyID through the query?**

Comment: Obligatory reading [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). Your question can be answered only if you use an anemic repository that simply aliases the methods of a specific DbSet property. That antipattern offers no benefits at best. Worst case, you actually break the built-in repository, Unit-of-Work and disconnected behavior of EF

Comment: What does `GetAll()` do? Unless it's just `return db.Reservation.Where(predicate);` you;ll have to post its code. Otherwise it's impossible to guess what the query is

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post the code for `GetAll()` or the `Reservation` and `Transaction` classes, so one can only guess.

`SelectMany` returns `Transaction` objects only. The next calls only see `Transaction` objects, not `Reservation`. If `Transaction` has a `Reservation` property, one could use `x.Reservation.CompanyId` to return that value, eg :

```
.Select(x => new 
{
    CompanyID = x.Transaction.CompanyId,
    Method = x.Method,
    Amount = x.Amount,
    VatAmount = x.VatAmount
});
```

In that case though, you shouldn't even start querying from `Reservation`. It would be better to query `Transactions`, eg :

```
var transactions = db.Transactions
                     .Where(x=>companyIds.Contains(x.Reservation.CompanyId) &&
                               x.DateCreated >= options.PaymentFromDate &&
                                x.DateCreated < endDate)
                     .Select(x => new 
                     {
                         CompanyId = x.Reservation.Id
                         Method = x.Method,
                         Amount = x.Amount,
                         VatAmount = x.VatAmount
                     });
```

**Missing Reservation property**

Add it. The data model is meant to facilitate the queries, and you obviously need that relation.

The relational model doesn't specify any kind of graph or hierarchy, that's its main benefit over other data models. Since you want *Transactions*, you should query transations. In SQL you'd only need to add a `JOIN` or `WHERE IN` clause to filter by Transaction and CompanyID.

**The Repository antipattern**

This exposes the next, far more serious problem. It looks like you're using the "generic" Repository **anti**pattern - a low-level Repository interface imposed over a higher-level ORM like EF Core. The problems with this are well known, check eg [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) or [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) from 2009.

A DbSet is already a repository. A DbContext already implements Unit-of-Work and disconnected operations, combining multiple entity repositories.

There's no need for anemic repositories to hide data access details, that's what the ORM is for. What would make sense is a **specialized, multi-entity** repository serving a specific use case, hiding the details of combining entities, validation checks, adding methods that implement common queries, for all the entities involved.

That specialized repository could have a `GetTransactionsByCompany(int)` method for example, that would encapsulate the entire query and really hiding the details.

Using an anemic repository for `Reservations` makes changing the query harder, without offering any benefits. The query's details are still exposed to the callers.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. I have to start the query with reservation because I am getting the corresponding transactions from the Reservation table.

Comment: @Spiderman this means the model needs fixing, not the query.

Answer (score 0):

To do not make transparent classes, better to use query syntax and everything is availaible.

```cs
var result = 
  from r in reservationRepository
  where companyIds.Contains(r.CompanyId)
  from t in t.Transactions
  where t.DateCreated >= options.PaymentFromDate
    && t.DateCreated < endDate
  select new 
  {
      CompanyId = r.CompanyId,
      Method = t.Method,
      Amount = t.Amount,
      VatAmount = t.VatAmount
  };
```